# Arrays in C++ - Adding elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition. I declared an integer array capable of holding 50 elements. Depending on how many entries the user gives, each of those entries will be stored as a separate element in the array. I want to add up all these unknown elements and print the answer to the console. Is it possible to do this, and how?

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a fixed size array, not a vector<int>?

Comment: Is this homework? Or just learning? Unless you need to keep the data for something else (or this is specific to a homework problem), you may not need an array at all.

Comment: It's both learning and homework/project.

Comment: Further, I've not yet been introduced to dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `std::accumulate()` from header `<numeric>`:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
```

If the user gives less then 50 elements then you need to account for that:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), arr + element_count, 0);
```

Comment: Good answer if all 50 elements are valid. How about `std::accumulate(arr, arr+numberOfEntriesTheUserGives, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too simple, but what about settin all elements to 0 (zero) at the beginning and then add all items in loop and finally print out the result of addition?

Comment: Thank you Kamil_H for your response. Would appreciate if you could kindly elaborate?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe something like this:
    `int myItems[50];`
    `memset(myItems, 0, 50*sizeof(int));`
    //here user inserts items to array
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++) result+=myItems[i];
    cout << result;`

Comment: Kamil_H, if you could supply me with your aforementioned code, it would really be of great use to me! Thanks a lot Kamil_H.